# spring boot with gradle 3 and java 7 fails at server startup

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-boot, ubuntu-12.04

I have started playing with gradle and spring boot and picked some nice 'n easy tutorials as listed below. My setup is also listed below.

Though the tutorial states that Java 1.8 is required, I have read that both gradle and boot can be used on Java 1.7 also.

So, any reason why this simple tutorial shouldn't work for Java 1.7? Apparently ...

I create my gradlew as follows: `gradle wrapper --gradle-version 3.0` and then run my gradle build command as ususal: `./gradlew build && java -jar build/libs/gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar` in my project directory.

Setup:

- OS: 12.04 LTS 32-bit
- java version "1.7.0_80"
- tutorials:

  - https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/#scratch
  - https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html

build.gradle (**NOTE**: I specify target/sourceCompatibility = 1.7):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.4.0.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-spring-boot'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

dependencies {
    // tag::jetty[]
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    }
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty")
    // end::jetty[]
    // tag::actuator[]
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    // end::actuator[]
    testCompile("junit:junit")
}
```

output:

Note that the error occurs at server startup, i.e. here:
`org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container`

```
vagrant@precise32:/vagrant/BootTutorial$ ./gradlew build && java -jar build/libs/gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:findMainClass
:jar
:bootRepackage
:assemble
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test UP-TO-DATE
:check UP-TO-DATE
:build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 4.835 secs

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.0.RELEASE)

2016-09-03 18:57:49.456  INFO 2043 --- [           main] hello.Application                        : Starting Application on precise32 with PID 2043 (/vagrant/BootTutorial/build/libs/gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar started by vagrant in /vagrant/BootTutorial)
2016-09-03 18:57:49.518  INFO 2043 --- [           main] hello.Application                        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-09-03 18:57:50.136  INFO 2043 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@65b0e5: startup date [Sat Sep 03 18:57:50 AEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-09-03 18:57:58.795  WARN 2043 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
2016-09-03 18:57:59.019 ERROR 2043 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:535) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at hello.Application.main(Application.java:13) [classes!/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58) [gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:189) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        ... 16 common frames omitted

vagrant@precise32:/vagrant/BootTutorial$
```

Comment: Please do not edit your question such that it invalidates existing answers. Instead, create a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Spring Boot 1.4, the default Jetty version is 9.3, which requires JDK8.

If you want to stick to JDK7, [you can use Jetty 9.2 as explained in the reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#howto-use-jetty-9.2).

Comment: thanks. i have  done the re-config for jetty 9.2 and updated my build.gradle file above. now i do get a new start-up error (see original post)

Comment: see issue below - silly me had tomcat running and not shut it down prior to setarting boot. works now. but - thanks a lot for pointing me to the jetty 9.2 post, that was the first issue

Comment: StackOverflow is not made just for your own use. It's meant to help other developers running into the same issue. Editing and changing the original question is certainly confusing for others, especially when it's been solved. Now what should people think? Was it the jetty version or the port in use? Which answer is solving *my problem*? Creating dedicated, well-formed questions is part of the game.

Comment: sorry mate ; did not do this on purpose. i have reverted my original post and given your post the solution. hope it's all good now. thanks for your feedback . cheers

Comment: It's all good. Now your question has a great potential to be popular and help tons of people. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you actually look at the stack? It clearly says "Port 8080 in use". There are two possibilities, either you have some kind of server or service listening to port 8080 or you have a hanging thread in the background from your last run.

Comment: thanks - indeed I still had tomcat running ; yeah I am still getting used to read/interpret the logs properly. now when I run the build command it starts the server and I can access the app in the browser - cheers !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your Application.java class looks like.But I'm guessing you are missing something like this.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(YourClassToRun.class, args);
  }
}
```

Comment: i have added my Application.java file in my original post. i only use the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation. do i need the others, or what are you referring to?